# How to export databases seperatly in oracle 11G

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

In Sql-developer i have 3 different connection and 3 different databases , and i want to export them separately.
Whenever i use expdp, it exports all of them together.
I want to back up databases separately.

Comment: You want 3 dmp files? That would be 3 data pump jobs

Comment: Yes i want 3 dmp files , because i have 3 different databases

Comment: So create and run 3 jobs

Comment: I created 3 different users for three databases but , they import the whole database

Comment: Then do a schema export

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like these are 3 different **users** (schemas) within the same database, not 3 different **databases**.

Therefore, you should use [schema mode](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_export.htm#i1007509) in order to export each of them separately.

Comment: i have 3 connections with 3 different databases imported, what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use the *Database Export* wizard in SQL Developer as it follows:

> To export metadata or data, or both, use the Export Wizard: click
> Tools, then Database Export

Source:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/server.112/e18804/impexp.htm#BABFDCDC